# Container view cut off in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uicontainerview

I have a view controller embed into a container view in iOS Xcode project. When I put a button at the bottom of this view controller it will not display in the container that is showing the view. My work around is right now is I added a scroll view. However I would like to get it to work without a scroll view (If possible).

Comment: You should provide some code or something that shows what you've tried to increase your chances of getting a helpful answer.

Comment: My problem was in interface builder, but thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button is not showing up indicates that the height of your view controller' view is greater than the display area for your view controller' view on the container view. Adjust your height to match the display height.

Comment: How would I change the height of my view controller if in the size inspector height and width are grayed out

Comment: Zoom out your storyboard. Select the viewcontroller (and not view). In attribute inspector you will get an option to change the size. set it to freeform and you can set your custom size.